# Is there a blender plugin that allows me to click on a material and see where it is used on the mesh/model?

Tags: materials

I have gotten another problem whit my project. The model i based my project on has 23 textures that are not named really usefully(some are in other language i dont speak).

Basically is there a way in blender to see(trough some plugins or external program) which material is used on which faces(so i could get a bigger picture what materials i can delete, re name, etc...)? Basically id like to see materials used on faces in sort of a same way like we can see selected faces in wireframe rendering mode(while the faces are chosen in edit mode).

Is there a plugin or external program(that i can buy or get for free) that allows me to see materials like this?

Where faces would be selected based on the material i have inputted into somewhere(eg clicked on the material in question)?

[image]

Comment: Tried the "Select" button in materials panels when you are in edit mode? Also Shift+G -> Select Similar -> Material.